# Getting the "max" of a string-based enum in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a collection of objects with a `role` of either `admin` or `regular` and wanted to pluck out the most permissive of those. The use case is for finding, in a set of teams, what the highest permission a user has in their team memberships.

I could do something hacky like `.max_by { |x| x.admin? ? 1 : 0 }`.

Is there a more conventional way to handle something of this nature?

Comment: Not clear what you mean.

Comment: @sawa Assume you have an array of `Team` objects that have a `role` of either `admin` or `regular`, where `admin` gives you higher permissions. You have two of these objects in your collection, one with `admin` and one with `regular`. We want our hypothetical logic to return `admin`, which is what my `max_by` example does. But I'm wondering if there's not a more conventional way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have strings or symbols as values of some attribute, it implies that they are not comparable in nature. If you have a notion of comparison among the values, then you should rather design that property to take an integer value in the first place. Giving integer values for comparable properties is seen in places such as safe level of commands that affect the OS. In your case, perhaps `1` for admin, `0` for regular. Associating `1` to admin and `0` to regular should then be done within the view-related logic when you want to give an output.

Comment: The reason a string was chosen as the data type was to avoid the problem with Rails `enums` where inserting a new role would require us to change these values. I'm wondering if we can maybe have some virtual `role_value` attribute that returns these integer values depending on the string?

Comment: Make an array of these role names, and use the index as the id of each string

Comment: For context for others reading, the issue I'm talking about here with the `enum` is this: https://bendyworks.com/rails-enum-sharp-knife/

Comment: Doesn't this link pretty much provide the solution to your problem?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I don't believe so, because creating a new value that's intermediate to `regular` and `admin` would lead to non-matching integer values. For example, if it were `0` and `1`, but we had a role less permissive than `admin`, we would need to do an intermediate migration step to work around this.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I'm thinking that your comment combined with OP's answer gets me the right direction. Something like `ROLES = ["regular", "admin"]` and `def role_value ROLES.index(self.role) end`, perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you want to store them as strings, but have the freedom to add more strings without breaking the comparison function. The array would work, until you want two roles to be equivalent - then you'd have to write a more complex comparison. But the general idea holds.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is sufficient for now. Thanks @AndrewWilliamson and OP both!